# SQL Alchemy datetime and database dialects

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have an application that I'm building and would like it to be portable to several databases, in particular MS SQL and PostgreSQL. The specific issue I'm facing is working with **datetime** datatypes.

For example, I would like to take the below history table and group by user_id, getting a total time for each user. Where time_in is Null, I need to get the current datetime.

**So my question is, do I need to write my SQL Alchemy code to be database specific?** Is there a way to acheive the same results of the below query without using a database specific function like `datdiff`?

Sample query that works for SQL Server but not PostgreSQL:

```
history_timecase = case([(History.time_in == None, func.now())], else_=History.time_in)

user_list = db.session.query(History.user_id, func.sum(func.datediff(text('minute'), History.time_in, history_timecase)))\
            .group_by(History.user_id).all()
```

---

History Table:

```
+----+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| id | user_id |    time_in     |    time_out     |
+----+---------+----------------+-----------------+
| 11 |       2 |                | 8/1/2017 8:14   |
| 12 |       2 |                | 8/1/2017 8:14   |
| 13 |       2 |                | 8/1/2017 8:14   |
| 14 |       2 |                | 8/1/2017 8:14   |
| 15 |       2 |                | 8/1/2017 8:14   |
| 16 |       2 |                | 8/1/2017 8:14   |
| 17 |      11 |                | 7/31/2017 11:30 |
|  6 |       6 | 8/1/2017 9:25  | 8/1/2017 8:06   |
| 18 |      12 |                | 8/1/2017 9:34   |
|  9 |       9 | 8/1/2017 9:40  | 8/1/2017 8:51   |
| 10 |      10 | 8/1/2017 10:00 | 8/1/2017 8:55   |
| 22 |      14 | 8/1/2017 10:00 | 8/1/2017 9:51   |
| 23 |      14 | 8/1/2017 10:00 | 8/1/2017 9:51   |
| 24 |      14 | 8/1/2017 10:00 | 8/1/2017 9:51   |
|  7 |       7 | 8/1/2017 10:15 | 8/1/2017 8:37   |
| 25 |      14 | 8/1/2017 10:15 | 8/1/2017 10:04  |
| 27 |      14 | 8/1/2017 10:15 | 8/1/2017 10:05  |
| 28 |      14 | 8/1/2017 10:15 | 8/1/2017 10:05  |
| 29 |      12 | 8/1/2017 10:15 | 8/1/2017 10:06  |
| 26 |      15 | 8/1/2017 10:45 | 8/1/2017 10:05  |
| 33 |      16 | 8/1/2017 11:15 | 8/1/2017 10:24  |
| 37 |      18 |                | 8/1/2017 11:19  |
| 34 |      17 | 8/1/2017 11:35 | 8/1/2017 10:38  |
| 30 |      14 | 8/1/2017 11:40 | 8/1/2017 10:18  |
| 31 |      14 | 8/1/2017 11:40 | 8/1/2017 10:18  |
| 32 |      14 | 8/1/2017 11:40 | 8/1/2017 10:18  |
+----+---------+----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Yes, because `datediff` is specific to SQL Server.

Comment: I am aware datediff is specific to SQL Server. I would like to know if there is another way to achieve what I am after without using a database specific function.

Comment: You could try to encapsulate as much of the DB specific code as possible to [custom compiled constructs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/compiler.html#further-examples). On the surface you'd provide a DB agnostic construct for some computation, under the hood it'd compile to DB specific implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

datediff() is too specific for sql server.

I'm posting a link for a suggested solution wherein he uses a custom subtract interval function in postgres:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sqlalchemy/6mSpNTMjUGU

```
  from sqlalchemy import func
  from sqlalchemy.sql.expression import FunctionElement
  from sqlalchemy.ext.compiler import compiles

  class subtract_interval(FunctionElement):
      type = Date()
      name = 'subtract_interval'

  @compiles(subtract_interval)
  def compile_subtract_interval(element, compiler, **kwargs):
      return '(%s::date - %s::interval)' % (
          compiler.process(element.clauses.clauses[0]),
          compiler.process(element.clauses.clauses[1]),
      )

  res = session.query(Foo).filter(
      Foo.date < subtract_interval(func.now(), '3 years')
  ).all()
```